# Use UniqueEntity on a Gedmo\Blameable field

Tags: php, validation, doctrine, symfony

I am using Gedmo extension in addition with Symfony 3.2 and Doctrine 2.5.6 and I'm encountering an issue. I can't make Gedmo\Blameable and UniqueEntity constraint work together. Indeed, the blamed field is still null at validation time. Is there any way to make it work or a possible work-around ?

Here is my entity

```
/**
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"author", "question"},
 *     errorPath="question",
 *     message="This author already has an answer for that Question"
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
 class TextAnswer
 {

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   * @Gedmo\Blameable(on="create")
   */
  private $author;

  /**
   * @Assert\NotNull()
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="textAnswers")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="question_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private $question;
}
```

Thanks

**EDIT : SOLUTION**

Rather than manually setting the user (which removes Gedmo\Blameable interests), I created my own entity validator.
I give it  doctrine and token storage as arguments so it can make a query on db to validate my criteria with the currently connected user (that will be later used by Gedmo\Blameable).

Comment: Thought this was in a foreign language at first _UniqueEntity Gedmo Blameable_

Answer (score 1):

The `BlameableListener` is invoked during the Doctrine's flush operation, which normally happens after the entity has been validated. That's why `$author` is `null` at validation time.

The most straightforward workaround is to set `$author` yourself beforehand.